# javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory ClassCastException

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I get on my local machine the following exception when running the tests by maven (mvn test).

```
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder@195ed659 - Parser configuration error occured 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
```

After googling around I came across several pages which describe the main problem behind it (several SAXParserFactoryImpl in different classloaders).

-> http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/702/

My question is, how can I figure out which library is also providing the SAXParserFactoryImpl, so that I can exclude it. I am using Maven, IntelliJ and JDK 1.6.0_23. The issue occurs on the command line as well as when running the tests from IntelliJ.

But the strange issue is, that on the build server this issue doesn't occur.

**Update 1**

Just figured out when I run the first time mvn test after an mvn clean, the error doesn't appear. But as soon as I run mvn test again (without clean, the exception occurs) (when I run it from IntelliJ).

When I run it on the cmd line, then several mvn test calls do work.

Comment: can you specify which jars you are using so that i come to know which makes conflict?

Comment: I uploaded the maven pom.xml to http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/039L.

Comment: Looking at your dependencies its probably an indirect dependency.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found the issue. It was related to PowerMockito who tried to load the SAXParserFactory. The reason why I haven't figured that one out was because the stacktrace contained only twice PowerMockito, and this at the middle :-)

So If you figure out this problem in IntelliJ and you do use PowerMockito, annotate your test class with the following annotation:

```
@PowerMockIgnore(["javax.management.*", "javax.xml.parsers.*",
         "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*", "ch.qos.logback.*", "org.slf4j.*"])
```

This has solved the problem in my case.

Comment: For future readers: when this happens due to logging, then (recommended) using `@MockPolicy(Slf4jMockPolicy.class)` or `@MockPolicy(Log4jMockPolicy.class)`, or otherwise excluding the logging framework with `@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.log4j.*")` or `@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.commons.logging.*")` might help. See [the PowerMock FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, actually it made the problem worse, after adding this annotation, my tests failed with the incoherent error `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.`

Comment: I should have known. PowerMock ruins everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your JDK probably has its own SAXParserFactoryImpl.

Check for jars like xercesImpl, xml/xml-api and sax.

One your server the one from the server is probably going to be used.

You can use a jarfinder: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~SAXParserFactoryImpl~

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error today. After a lot of digging, I found that the solutions here, or on other places are not helpful.

However, after playing around, I found a solution that works deterministically, unlike the accepted answer which does not apply to all cases.

**The answer is, look through stack trace to find any ClassCast exceptions, and just add them to \@PowerMockIgnore list. Keep repeating until the issue is solved.** Worked like magic for me.