# Remove xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar from the application

Tags: java, jar

Per the recommendation from here: [WAS 8.5: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585014/was-8-5-java-lang-classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryim), I've looked through all the jars and cannot find xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar. I did remove crimson_1.1.1.jar from my project but that did not alter the error (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory). I looked for the method in question (SAXParserFactoryImpl) and found it here: C:\Program Files\IBM\IBMIMShared\plugins\org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v200805270400.jar. Since this jar is part of the Websphere installation, how can I remove it? Or does it need to be updated with a newer version that resolves this incompatibility?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. With the goal of replacing crimson_1.1.1.jar, I looked for other jars (on my machine) having the class SAXParserFactoryimpl. I found it in several jars, two in particular: xercesimpl-2.8.0 and xercesimpl-2.9.1. I ultimately picked xercesimpl-2.8.0.jar because I needed to include another jar in my app, commons-fileupload-1.2.jar. When I downloaded this commons package to include it into my app, it came with xercesimpl-2.8.0.jar. So with that as the connection, I removed all references to crimson_1.1.1.jar and replaced it with xercesimpl-2.8.0.jar in my application. I also had to set my EAR's deployment descriptor (EAR > deployment descriptor > Deployment tab > Application section) to PARENT_FIRST for Classloader mode and APPLICATION for WAR classloader policy. So with the jars swapped and the deployment descriptor modified, the server started up w/o error and no longer got this incompatibility error and my application was finally working!